# VB.NET - Passing an event as a parameter

Tags: vb.net, events, parameters

I need to pass an event as a parameter to a function. Is there a way of doing this?

The reason is that I have a sequence of two lines of code that is littered all over my program, where I dynamically remove the handler to an event, and then set the handler again. I'm doing this for several different events and event handlers, so I've decided to write a function that does this.

As an example, let's say I have a combobox in my code called combobox1, and I have the handler called indexChangedHandler. In several places of my code, I have the following two lines:

```
RemoveHandler combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf indexChangedHandler
AddHandler combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf indexChangedHandler
```

Now, I don't want to keep on repeating the above two lines of code (or similar) all over my program, so I'm looking for a way to do this:

```
Private Sub setHandler(evt As Event, hndler As eventhandler)
     RemoveHandler evt, hndler
     AddHandler evt, hndler
End Sub
```

so that everywhere where those two lines of code(or similar) occur in my program, I can just replace them with:

```
setHandler(combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf indexChangedHandler)
```

So far, the "evt as Event" part of the argument of the setHandler function is giving an error.

P.S: I've asked this question on a couple of other forums and keep getting asked why I would want to set the handler immediately after removing it. The reason is because dynamically adding an event handler n-times causes the handler to be executed n-times when the event occurs. To avoid this, that is, to ensure that the handler is executed just once when the event occurs, I first remove the handler each time I want to add the handler dynamically.

You might be asking why the handler would be added several times in the first place... The reason is because I add the handler only after a particular event, say E1, in my form has occurred (I add the handler within the handler of event E1). And event E1 can occur several times within my form. If I do not remove the handler each time before adding it again, the handler gets added and thus executed several times.

Whatever the case, the processing occurring within the function is not of ultimate importance to me at this time, but rather just the means of passing an event as a parameter.

Comment: Can you let us know what the error is?

Comment: There is no real way to do this programatically, since you cannot pass references to an event member.  I'm also not exactly sure what setHandler is supposed to do... can you clarify why you would need to remove an event handler and then add it right back again?

Comment: @cdhowie I was in the process of editing my post to explain why I would need to do this, got interrupted, came back and completed the editing and submitted, before realising you've asked the question already. Long story short, the reason is now included in the original post :)

Comment: I see.  Unfortunately, there really is no way to do what you are asking here...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Of course you can pass events around... Well you can pass `Action(Of EventHandler)` which can do what you want.

If you have a class that defines an event like so:

```
Public Class ComboBox
    Public Event SelectedIndexChanged As EventHandler   
End Class
```

Given an instance of `ComboBox` you can then create add & remove handler actions like so:

```
Dim combobox1 = New ComboBox()

Dim ah As Action(Of EventHandler)
    = Sub (h) AddHandler combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged, h
Dim rh As Action(Of EventHandler)
    = Sub (h) RemoveHandler combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged, h
```

(Now, this is VB.NET 4.0 code, but you can do this in 3.5 using `AddressOf` and a little more mucking about.)

So if I have a handler `Foo`:

```
Public Sub Foo(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("Over here with Foo!")
End Sub
```

And a `Raise` method on `ComboBox` I can now do this:

```
ah(AddressOf Foo)
combobox1.Raise()
rh(AddressOf Foo)
```

This writes the message "Over here with Foo!" as expected.

I can also create this method:

```
Public Sub PassActionOfEventHandler(ByVal h As Action(Of EventHandler))
    h(AddressOf Foo)
End Sub
```

I can pass around the event handler actions like so:

```
PassActionOfEventHandler(ah)
combobox1.Raise()
PassActionOfEventHandler(rh)
```

Which again writes the message "Over here with Foo!".

Now, one issue that might be a problem is that you can accidentally swap the add and remove event handler delegates in code - after all they are the same type. So it is easy to just define strongly-typed delegates for the add and remove actions like so:

```
Public Delegate Sub AddHandlerDelegate(Of T)(ByVal eh as T)
Public Delegate Sub RemoveHandlerDelegate(Of T)(ByVal eh as T)
```

The code to define the delegate instances doesn't change except for the delegate types:

```
Dim ah As AddHandlerDelegate(Of EventHandler)
    = Sub (h) AddHandler combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged, h
Dim rh As RemoveHandlerDelegate(Of EventHandler)
    = Sub (h) RemoveHandler combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged, h
```

So this now lets you be very creative. You can define a function that will take the add handler delegate, the remove handler delegate and a event handler, which will wire-up an event handler, and then return to you an `IDisposable` that you can use later to remove the handler without needing to retain a reference to the event handler. This is handy for using `Using` statements.

Here's the signature:

```
Function SubscribeToEventHandler(
    ByVal h as EventHandler,
    ByVal ah As AddHandlerDelegate(Of EventHandler),
    ByVal rh As RemoveHandlerDelegate(Of EventHandler)) As IDisposable
```

So given this function I can now do this:

```
combobox1.Raise()
Using subscription = SubscribeToEventHandler(AddressOf Foo, ah, rh)
    combobox1.Raise()
    combobox1.Raise()
End Using
combobox1.Raise()
```

And this writes the message "Over here with Foo!" only twice. The first and last `Raise` calls are outside of the subscription to the event handler.

Enjoy!

Comment: If I understand this right, you're passing `Delegates` around, not the `Events` itself, as asked in the question. A very good answer nonetheless.

Comment: Enigmativity, thanks for your detailed answer. It was somewhat hard for me to understand though, since I saw some strange looking constructs in your post (my first time of seeing such syntax, so please bare with me). But from what I've understood, I must always first explicitely define the object and the event in "ah" and "rh" right? what I'd like to know is, is there anyway of not limiting the definition of "ah" to "combobox1.selectedIndexChanged", so that I can use thesame function to set the handler on a different object(cbx2), say, "cbx2.selectedIndexChanged".

Comment: @`Tracer` - Yes. Just change the delegate definitions to `Public Delegate Sub AddHandlerDelegate(Of T)(ByVal eh as T, comboBox as ComboBox)` and you can make it work for any `ComboBox`. if you have to do other events I'd suggest calling the delegate `AddSelectedIndexChangedHandler` etc. An add and remove delegate for each event and control.

Comment: @`Bobby` - Events are essentially delegates - `Public Delegate Sub EventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)`. I'm replacing one delegate with another. Well actually, I'm creating a closures over the `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` calls and passing around a delegate for each closure. :-)

Comment: @Enigmativity: Stop putting names into Code-Tags, that breaks @-comment-notifications. ;) And yes, exactly, that was my answer. ;) But you shouldn't mix this, there's a slight and very subtle difference if you do that or if you pass the `Event` (as asked) directly around. Anyway +1.

Comment: @Bobby - What do you mean by breaking the @-comment-notifications? There's no formal notification based on me typing "@SomeName", right?

Comment: @Enigmativity: There is, if you write @name that person will be notified (if he has engaged in the discussion, or something). Using code-tags around the name will break that. ^^ See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work for further information.

Comment: @Bobby - Thanks for that. I thought it was just a convention and not a notification feature. I'll make sure I do the right thing in the future. Cheers.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I'm going with your answer as it approaches the most what I was intending to do, though not as flexible as I would have liked it. But as I've come to find out with both your and Bobby's help, it's not possible to do exactly what I wanted to do(which is to have only one function to which the event and the event handler is passed). Thanks to both of you for your active participation thus far.

Comment: @Tracer - Much appreciated. I'm actually looking at trying to write a library that will allow your scenario to work by passing around an `IEvent<TEventArgs>` that will allow code to subscribe to the event. It should be as easy as you were hoping for. Just investigating at the moment. Alternatively you could look at the reactive extensions - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/threads - which does want you want and more, but will require you to learn a new paradigm.

Comment: @Enigmativity, thanks for the pointer. I'll take a look at it sometime later. Good luck in your library endeavour, and if it's not too much to ask, please keep me posted.

Comment: @Enigmativity Please keep me posted too, I'd very much like to have that library at my fingertips :D

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass events around. `Event` isn't a type, it's a keyword that defines a pair of methods, add and remove, used to change the state of the event member of the class. They are very much like properties in this respect (which have get and set methods).

Like properties, the add and remove methods can do whatever you want. Typically, these will do nothing more than maintain a delegate instance, which itself is a `MulticastDelegate` or in other words, a list of delegates which are getting called one by one if the event is raised.

You can clearly see this structure in C#, where it is not masked with `AddHandler`/`RemoveHandler`, but you directly edit the list of associated handlers: `myObject.Event += new Delegate(...);`.

And, again like properties, being a member of a class that actually abstracts two different methods, it's not possible to literally pass an event as an object.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different meanings for the term "event", depending upon context. In the context you are seeking, an Event is a matched pair of methods that will effectively add or remove a delegate from a subscription list. Unfortunately, there's no class in VB.NET to represent a method address without an attached object. One could probably use [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata_%28CLI%29#Reflection) to fetch the appropriate methods, and then pass those methods to a routine that would call them both, but in your particular situation that would probably be silly.

The only situation where I can see that it might be useful to pass an event in the sense you describe would be for something like an [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) object which subscribes to events from longer-lived objects, and which needs to unsubscribe all of its events when it is disposed. In that case, it may be helpful to use reflection to fetch the remove-delegate method for each event, and then call all of the remove-delegate methods when an object is disposed. Unfortunately, I know of no way to represent the events to be retrieved except as string literals, whose validity could not be checked until run-time.